# variable parameters in Scala constructor

Tags: scala

I would like to write a Matrix class in Scala from that I can instantiate objects like this:

```
val m1 = new Matrix( (1.,2.,3.),(4.,5.,6.),(7.,8.,9.) )

val m2 = new Matrix( (1.,2.,3.),(4.,5.,6.) )

val m3 = new Matrix( (1.,2.),(3.,4.) )

val m4 = new Matrix( (1.,2.),(3.,4.),(5.,6.) )
```

I have tried this:

```
class Matrix(a: (List[Double])* ) { }
```

but then I get a type mismatch because the matrix rows are not of type List[Double].

Further it would be nice to just have to type Integers (1,2,3) instead of (1.,2.,3.) but still get a double matrix.

How to solve this?

Thanks!
Malte

Answer (score 1):

`(1.0, 2.0)` is a `Tuple2[Double, Double]` not a `List[Double]`. Similarly `(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)` is a `Tuple3[Double, Double, Double]`.

If you need to handle a fixed number of cardinality, the simplest solution in plain vanilla scala would be to have

```
class Matrix2(rows: Tuple2[Double, Double]*)
class Matrix3(rows: Tuple3[Double, Double, Double]*)
```

and so on.

Since there exist an implicit conversion from `Int` to `Double`, you can pass a tuple of ints and it will be automatically converted.

```
new Matrix2((1, 2), (3, 4))
```

---

If you instead need to abstract over the row cardinality, enforcing an `NxM` using types, you would have to resort to some more complex solutions, perhaps using the shapeless library.

Or you can use an actual list, but you cannot restrict the cardinality, i.e. you cannot ensure that all rows have the same length (again, in vanilla scala, shapeless can help)

```
class Matrix(rows: List[Double]*)
new Matrix(List(1, 2), List(3, 4))
```

---

Finally, the `1.` literal syntax is deprecated since scala 2.10 and removed in scala 2.11. Use `1.0` instead.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to use the class for matrices with sizes of n*m where 0<n<=1000 and 0<m<=1000.
Well, the manual instanciation will be probably for a size of up to 10x10. But there should not be different classes for different sizes.

Comment: and

    new Matrix(List(1, 2), List(3, 4))

is too verbose :(

Comment: Well in that case surely you cannot use tuples, as they go up to 22 in scala. I'm afraid you will have to use lists, and beware that in this way you're not even enforcing that all rows have the same length.

Answer (score 1):

If you need support for very large matrices, consider using an existing implementation like [Breeze](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze). Breeze has a [DenseMatrix](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Data-Structures#densematrix) which probably meets your requirements. For performance reasons, Breeze offloads more complex operations into native code.

Getting Matrix algebra right is a difficult exercise and unless you are specifically implementing matrix to learn/assignment, better to go with proven libraries.

Edited based on comment below:

You can consider the following design.

```
class Row(n : Int*)
class Matrix(rows: Row*) {...}
```

Usage:

```
val m = new Matrix(Row(1, 2, 3), Row(2,3,4))
```

You need to validate that all Rows are of the length and reject the input if they are not.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Breeze uses a constructor like DenseMatrix(rows: Int, cols: Int, data: Array[Double]).
I would like to create a Matlab-Like library that is easy to use for scientists with just a few programming skills. Its usage should feel like math and not like computer science.

Answer (score 0):

I have hacked a solution in an - I think - a bit unscala-ish way

```
class Matrix(values: Object*) { // values is of type WrappedArray[Object]
  var arr : Array[Double] = null
  val rows : Integer = values.size
  var cols : Integer = 0

  var _arrIndex = 0
  for(row <- values) {
    // if Tuple (Tuple extends Product)
    if(row.isInstanceOf[Product]) {
      var colcount = row.asInstanceOf[Product].productIterator.length
      assert(colcount > 0, "empty row")
      assert(cols == 0 || colcount == cols, "varying number of columns")
      cols = colcount

      if(arr == null) {
        arr = new Array[Double](rows*cols)
      }

      for(el <- row.asInstanceOf[Product].productIterator) {
        var x : Double = 0.0
        if(el.isInstanceOf[Integer]) {
          x = el.asInstanceOf[Integer].toDouble
        }
        else {
          assert(el.isInstanceOf[Double], "unknown element type")
          x = el.asInstanceOf[Double]
        }

        arr(_arrIndex) = x
        _arrIndex = _arrIndex + 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

works like

```
object ScalaMatrix extends App {
  val m1 = new Matrix((1.0,2.0,3.0),(5,4,5))
  val m2 = new Matrix((9,8),(7,6))
  println(m1.toString())
  println(m2.toString())
}
```

I don't really like it. What do you think about it?

Comment: it's kind of messy and far from functional, but most importantly you're still limited to 22 elements.

Comment: yeah, that's true. I can accept the 22 element limit for Tuples as the user most probably only will type in matrixes smaller than 10x10. Bigger matrices would be created by code - either by providing the data array or by setting row/column vectors or single elements. This still has to be implemented.